# Android: how does the execute() method in AsyncTask work?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So I am currently learning about AsyncTask in Android and there is the following simple example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = task.execute("http://someURL").get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("Result",result);
    }
}
```

The only thing I don't understand about the example is the following:

In the `try` section there is a string being passed to the `execute` method. The `execute` method is part of the `task` object. The `doInBackground` method is also part of the `task` object. How does the `doInBackground` method know about the content that I am passing to the `execute` method? Because in the tutorial I learned, that the `url = new URL(urls[0]);` contains the info of the string that is passed through the `execute` method. Can someone explain this connection to me?

Comment: `result = task.execute("http://someURL").get();` Oh Oh Oh.  Please do away with the .get(). Yo are abusing the async task in that way. Never use .get(). Instead handle the result in onPostExecute(). Override onPostExecute to begin with.

Comment: `Can someone explain this connection to me?` There is nothing to explain. That is how the AsyncTask class works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `DownloadTask` is a direct child class of `AsyncTask.` `AsyncTask` provides an implementation to manage a task in async way and you don't need to worry about any details about thread pool or any other details. `AsyncTask` class uses Java generics, i.e. a template with three parameters. You are using String as first and third parameter of the template, so it means doInBackground will take a variant number of `String` objects and it will return a `String` object. The "connection" between execute method and `doInBackground` is inside `AsyncTask` class and it's hidden in the parent class, it's the encapsulation and information hiding usually performed in object oriented design.

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: So inside the ```AsyncTask``` there is a  method or something that takes the string from the ```execute``` method and "shares" it with the ```doInBackground``` method?